# Apache ModRewrite keeps redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup a site on my local Windows machine (PHP, Apache 2.4) and my redirect rules are creating an inifinite loop. I can't figure out why.

My **hosts** file:

```
127.0.0.1   learn.loc
127.0.0.1   www.learn.loc
```

My Apache **httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\websites\learn"
    ServerName learn.loc
    ServerAlias www.learn.loc
    ErrorLog "logs/learn.loc-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/learn.loc-access.log" common

    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace2

    #PHP SETTINGS
    php_value auto_prepend_file "C:\websites\learn\noop.php"
    php_value open_basedir "C:\websites\learn"
    php_value error_log "C:\websites\learn\php_error.log"

    <Directory "C:\websites\learn">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

The **.htaccess** (located in `C:\websites\learn`)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^yii   /yii-v1/blog
RewriteRule ^yii/(.*)   /yii-v1/blog/$1
```

The webpage I'm trying to access is at `C:\websites\learn\yii-v1\blog\index.php`. When I enter `learn.loc/yii`, the web browser is redirected indefinitely.  The `ModRewrite` trace shows:

```
[rid#1330178/initial] rewrite 'yii/blog/' -> '/yii/blog'
[rid#1330178/initial] trying to replace context docroot C:/websites/learn with context prefix 
[rid#1330178/initial] internal redirect with /yii/blog [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#1331880/initial/redir#1] rewrite 'yii/blog' -> '/yii/blog'
[rid#1331880/initial/redir#1] trying to replace context docroot C:/websites/learn with context prefix 
[rid#1331880/initial/redir#1] internal redirect with /yii/blog [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#1334a40/initial/redir#2] rewrite 'yii/blog' -> '/yii/blog'
[rid#1334a40/initial/redir#2] trying to replace context docroot C:/websites/learn with context prefix 
[rid#1334a40/initial/redir#2] internal redirect with /yii/blog [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#1335b88/initial/redir#3] rewrite 'yii/blog' -> '/yii/blog'
[rid#1335b88/initial/redir#3] trying to replace context docroot C:/websites/learn with context prefix 
[rid#1335b88/initial/redir#3] internal redirect with /yii/blog [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#1336e30/initial/redir#4] rewrite 'yii/blog' -> '/yii/blog'
...
```

Notice that the request ids (first column) are different so there is some sort of infinite recursion happening, and I can't figure out why. There are no Apache or PHP errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must anchor your regex pattern in `RewriteRule` to avoid this problem:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^yii/?$   /yii-v1/blog [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^yii/(.+)$ /yii-v1/blog/$1 [L,NC]
```

Your regex pattern `^yii` matches any URI that starts with `/yii` and since your rewritten URI is also starting with `/yii` hence it keeps rewriting until Apache `mod_rewrite` module reaches max limit set at Apache server level or by default i.e. `10`.

This limit can be changed in Apache config using this directive:

```
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=20
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Could you please explain what was going on so I and others can learn from my mistake?

Comment: Yes I just added in answer.

Comment: Ok I get it.  It's still too early for the site to let me accept your answer. Do you know what "*trying to replace context docroot*" in the ModRewrite trace actually mean?

Comment: That line doesn't show up in my rewrite logs but I believe that is a debug level message to indicate that filesystem `DocumentRoot` i.e. `C:/websites/learn` has been stripped out while rewriting.